# Show gray scale image in colored only for child element

Tags: html, css, image-processing

I want to set the background image in grayscale, but it should be in colored for particular div or section.

Please see my code

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
   .parent{
     height: 300px;
     width: 450px;
     background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/450/") 50% 50% no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
     filter: grayscale(100%);
     position:relative;
   }
  .child{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     -moz-border-radius: 50px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
     border-radius: 50px;
     border: 2px solid #fff;
     position:absolute;
     top:35%;
     left:35%;
     filter: none;
   }
```

[Here is the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/x78q8p00/)

I want to show the colored background for child element which is set to parent.
Please suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: You need to make your html child-parent elements to be siblings (at the same level) because you can't undo a filter.

Comment: you could also take a look at   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode  example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Nvwpoq  support http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode